# Python: How to setup cx_Freeze script when located in different folder than main script?

Tags: python, windows, cx-freeze

I want to have the cx_Freeze setup script (setup.py) in a different folder than the main Python script (Main.py). If I place both scripts to the same folder, the gemerated EXE file works without a problem, but if I place the cx_Freeze script in the `..\scripts` folder (relative to Main.py) and specify the path to the executable using `cx_Freeze.Executable('..\\src\\Main.py')`, I get the error:`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named ’config’`. The `config` is a module located in the same directory as the Main.py script.

I've also tried putting `os.chdir('..\\src')` before the `cx_Freeze.setup()` call, but that didn't help.

Any ideas how to configure the cx_Freeze setup script in my case?

Answer (score 0):

So I've solved the problem by converting the relative path: `..\\src` into the absolute path and adding it to the `sys.path` runtime Python variable before executing `cx_Freeze.setup()`. In other words, I have the following at the beginning of the cx_Freeze setup script:

```
import os
import sys

import cx_Freeze

sys.path.append(os.path.realpath(sys.path[0] + '\\..\\src'))
```

#### Explanation

The Python `sys.path` variable contains list of paths which are examined when Python looks for modules. So the goal was to add there the absolute path to the folder where my modules are located.